# Solution required for Java JMX RMI Accessible with Common Credentials (Unauthenticated check)

Tags: java, tomcat, rmi, jmx, tcserver

I need help in resolving below vulnerability. We have this in our tomcat instance running version 7 and Java "1.8.0_242".
It was detected in 1099 port. This RMI port is not configured in any configuration file as its default port and also I am not seeing any RMI related configuration in setenv.sh or server.xml or catalina.properties , I am clueless how to disable this RMI port

In Dev also we had this but after we removing the below entry from setenv.sh, 1099 port not listening and the vulnerability disappeared , But in our prod environment, we dont have this entry at all.

CATALINA_OPTS=-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=1098 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=true -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.password.file
=/var/opt/vmware/vfabric-tc-server-standard/inst1/conf/jmxremote.password -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.access.file=/var/opt/vmware/vfabric-tc-server-standard/inst1/conf/jmxremote.access

Vulnerability:

Java JMX interface is accessible via following username/password pairs:
admin/password 
admin/admin 
admin/activemq 
monitorRole/QED 
controlRole/R%26D
controlrole/password 
monitorrole/password 
cassandra/cassandrapassword 
monitorRole/tomcat 
controlRole/tomcat 
monitorRole/mrpasswd 
controlRole/crpasswd 
role1/role1passwd 
role2/role2passwd 
role3/role3passwd 
admin/thisIsSupposedToBeAStrongPassword! 
QID Detection Logic (Authenticated): 
This QID tries to log into JMX RMI server using above credentials.

Note:if remote JMX RMI sever accessible without authentication. all of above credentials will post.

Comment: Any solution you for for this ? We have the same issue